# iOS Core Data sometimes is delayed in loading

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an app that's been available in the app store for a few years that uses Core Data. When the app is launched, the user is taken to the app's home screen where a few buttons are shown. Clicking any of the buttons takes the user to another screen that shows data that is loaded from Core Data in a UITableView (each button takes the user to different data). This is basic functionality that's been working in my app just fine the entire time the app's been available.

At some point last year, I noticed that at random times, the data saved in the app sometimes wouldn't load right away. The first time this happened, I clicked one of the buttons and was taken to a blank screen. I went back to the home screen and tried other buttons, and each screen was blank, so I thought all of my data had been wiped somehow. I proceeded to head back to the home screen and just sat there thinking for about 15 seconds, then I clicked one of the buttons again, but this time the data appeared. All of the other screens had data now as well.

I haven't updated the app in quite a while, so my code is unchanged. I don't recall there being a new iOS release around the time I started observing the issue, but it's possible.

This has happened a few more times since I first discovered it (3 or 4 times total over the last 6 months), but there seems to be no pattern at all. Once the data finally loads during these situations, it always loads right away from that point forward. This has made it impossible for me to debug it, because I can't force this situation to happen (99% of the time the data loads immediately).

Has anyone encountered this before, or have any recommendations on how to proceed? I've witnessed this on the Simulator and once on an actual device.

Comment: Are you loading a lot of data? How do you load it? To put it another way: what code do you think might be running during the delay?

Comment: No, it's not a lot of data. During the times when I observed this behavior, I always had limited test data (only a few records that weren't heavy duty).

Answer (score 0):

Random delays in updating your UI are a classic sign of attempting to update the UI from outside the main queue. It'll work, usually, but it may be delayed, and the delays won't be consistent. Make sure that when you try to update the UI, you're on the main queue. Use `DispatchQueue.main.async()` if necessary.

Assuming that you're using Xcode 9, make sure the main thread checker is turned on. That'll help you find this kind of problem when you're running the app from Xcode. Go to the target pop-up at the top of Xcode's window and select "Edit scheme...". In the "Run" section of the window, go to "Diagnostics" and make sure "Main Thread Checker" is turned on.

[image: Main Thread Checker]

Comment: Thanks Tom, I'll give this a try and report back!